# Flutter/ Firebase The getter 'length' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, provider

I develop Flutter app using Firebase as backend and when I move from screen to another BottomNavigationBar and I am using StreamProvider to pass the Profile data to the other screen.

When I move to another screen I receive this error:

```
 The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ProfileList
```

Here is ProfileList and ProfileTile

```
class ProfileList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfileListState createState() => _ProfileListState();
}

class _ProfileListState extends State<ProfileList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

final profiles = Provider.of<List<Profile>>(context);

return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: profiles.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index){
      return ProfileTile(profile: profiles[index]);
});
  }
}
```

ProfileTile

```
class ProfileTile extends StatefulWidget {
  final Profile profile;
  ProfileTile({this.profile});
  @override
  _ProfileTileState createState() => _ProfileTileState();
}

class _ProfileTileState extends State<ProfileTile> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 6, 20, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          title: Text(widget.profile.userName),
          subtitle: Text(widget.profile.city),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it seems the,

> itemCount: profiles.length,

part is rendered before the provider send data to it. so the profile variable is null.

try this,

```
itemCount: (profiles == null) ? 0 : profile.length,
```

Comment: That`s right buddy.. Thank you a lot for the help it worked